# How to Change UITabBar color in the app delegate?

Tags: iphone, tabbar

I was looking through this site in order to try and find a way in which I can change the color of my tabbar through the app delegate.

Every time i tried add the created view to the tab bar my app would crash immediately.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot change the color of UITabbar in iPhone application, it should be always in the default color. This is one of the UI design guidelines we have to follow, while developing applications for iOS.